# Remmina rdp session - no toolbar and keyboard shortcuts don't work

Tags: shortcut-keys, 14.10, remote-desktop, fullscreen, remmina

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.10 and I copied over my .remmina folder from my old 14.04 install and all my connections are there however when I connect to remote windows computer through rdp which is displayed fullscreen (which I want) I don't get the grey toolbar when I move the mouse to the top of the screen. Using the keyboard shortcut F4 to disconnect does not disconnect the session so the only way I can get out if it is to kill it through the system monitor.

Any ideas how to resolve this as it is extremely frustrating?

Answer (score 72):

To exit full screen mode in Remmina, press the right hand side <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key and <kbd>f</kbd> together.

Comment: Confusingly enough for me  it only worked with the ctrl key on the right side of the keyboard.

Comment: I believe that the host key assignment determines which control key is used to activate the keyboard shortcuts. My host key was Control_R and changed it to Control_L and toggling full screen works again but then using left ctrl + c no longer works on the remote machine as this has been taken over as the host assignment key. It's a win/lose situation I guess.

Comment: It is easy to change it to the left-hand Ctrl key - see my answer below.

Answer (score 3):

It's a bug, see
https://github.com/FreeRDP/Remmina/wiki/Remmina-Usage-FAQ point 3

It's apparently fixed but not in the version that ships with yakkety.

As a workaround you can use <kbd>HostKey</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> (HostKey can be set in **Edit > Settings > Keyboard** and by default is set to the right <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key). <kbd>HostKey</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd> toggles the Fullscreen Mode and you can go back to your normal Desktop if the remmina-window is not in fullscreen.

Answer (score 1):

Ok I can disconnect by using CTRL_R + F4 however I cannot get T for show/hide toolbar to work no matter what I key combo I use with it.

I've renamed the .remmina folder and and restarted remmina and recreated one of my connections and I get the same issue so I guess it's a bug (as they still have the reference to the toolbar in shortcuts so doesn't look like they've removed it).

Answer (score 1):

You are correct, even the 1.2 release of Remmina doesn't properly show the tabs or exit in Ubuntu.

I found that if I use the <kbd>Right Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> I can switch between remote sessions, and that in a Windows Server 2012 session I can bring up the menu to power off and a small menu pops up labeled 'disconnect.' Only in that way was I able to shut down the session.

Answer (score 0):

I'm running Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with remmina.

You can always use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to your desktop and to the remmina control screen.  Just like with Windows.

When you get to the control screen you can use Edit -> Preferences -> Keyboard.

The top option is the "Host key"

Click on the box that says "Control_R" and then it will prompt you to press another key.

In my case, my mini-keyboard does not have a Right-hand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> key, so I press the Left one.

It then displays "Control_L" and I click on "Close" then click on the maximized window which is underneath.

You can also use <kbd>Alt</kbd> + <kbd>Tab</kbd> to get back to the full-screen session.

Voila, the left-hand <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>f</kbd> works to un-maximize it and bring back the toolbars on top.